# How to remove the auto correct line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to remove the line that doesn't allow me to move move freely... Every time I try to edit a portion of a code it does edit the entire code, forcing me to write it again. It drives me mad!

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Which line is it in that screenshot? Do you get an error or alert of some kind which prevents you from moving freely? Have you tried closing the open tags/elements to make a complete document?

Comment: it's like LPChip said, the Insert key was everything, thanx anyway for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the <kbd>insert</kbd> key on your keyboard to change from replace to insert mode. This is a key that works since MS-DOS, and is something that works everywhere in windows, not just NotePad++